# Why does the file dialogue for a program (FreeFileSync) show different files than Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, flatpak

Today I was saving a file through a program called FreeFileSync and I noticed in the file dialogue that (what appeared to be) my root folder contained a folder called "app" that I've never seen before.

So, I went to my root folder using Nautilus and, indeed, the folder called "app" isn't there. After a little more exploration, I noticed that **the file dialogue for FFS sees many files that Nautilus apparently cannot see. Its like Nautilus and FFS both see totally different file systems.**

I have "show hidden files" enabled, so that shouldn't be the problem. I suspect that this has something to do with the fact that I installed FFS as a flatpak package, but I've installed other flatpak packages and the file dialogue from those packages sees the same thing that Nautilus sees.

What is going on!?

[image]

Comment: I would expect you to show us a long list (`ls -l`) so the permissions are visible for the folder "app". Are you sure these are the same locations? I see a `.flatpak-info` in 1 and not the other suggesting hidden files are not shown on the left OR you have 1 of the 2 installed as a snap and are looking at the internal file structure of that snap. Mind the Nautilus ALSO considers files as hidden when they are included in a file called ".hidden". So it is not just dot-files that are not shown.

Comment: So this could be caused by FFS being installed as a snap? Where can I read more about how snaps could cause this behavior? Also, I’m not sure how to make the permissions show up in the FFS file dialogue.

Comment: Wait you tagged this flatpak. See https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html Flatpack has its own permissions but I do agree that this is the wrong way: you have an issue with nautilus but it is a good read for flatpak users :)

Comment: When I use the “ls -l” command while the terminal is in the root folder, I also can’t see the “app” folder. So, I think the file dialogue for FFS is showing me that FFS “sees” something other than the true file structure. Is that how a flatpak is supposed to behave?

Comment: Yes https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak-docs/issues/109 You could be looking at `$appdir/data/`  (and $appdir = `XDG_DATA_HOME`)